Treat warnings as errors in custom targets
Thanks to this post, I'm treating warnings as error when building my Visual Studio solution (generated by CMake).
However, I have a custom target building projects documentation using Doxygen:
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT           doc/html/index.html
    COMMAND          doxygen
    ARGS             ...
    COMMENT          "Generating documentation..."
    VERBATIM)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( GENERATE_DOCUMENTATION ALL SOURCES doc/html/index.html )

When doxygen generates warnings (reporting a function is not documented for instance), I can see the Warning in Visual Studio's console. However, this warning is not treated as an error. Looks like only "compilation warnings" are treated as errors.
Is there a way to treat custom target warnings as errors?
I tried:
set_property(TARGET SDE_DOCUMENTATION PROPERTY COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON)

But it does not work.

It seems like you treat COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR property as a CMake magic, which automatically affects on every tool used during the build. Actually, this property affects only on the command line parameters, which CMake generates for invoke a compiler. When use add_custom_command you are fully specifying both a tool and its parameters. If you need specific behavior of the tool, then pass appropriate parameter(s) to it.

Good point, I added WARN_AS_ERROR = ON in my doxyfile and it did the job. Though a global CMake way to do this would be a better solution.

If you want CMake to generate a doxyfile, then you could look into module FindDoxygen.cmake. I haven't find an option about making warnings as errors, but may be setting
variable DOXYGEN_WARN_AS_ERROR to ON before calling doxygen_add_docs will work.
